# Out-of-focus color in reflective microscopy with Köhler EPI-illumination

Tags: optics, lenses, microscopy

It is well known that Köhler illuminator in optical microscopy is designed in a way to ensure uniform illumination of the field, often with adjustable apertures to allow as little light as possible to fully illuminate useful field of view / microscope lens aperture.

Aberrations of the illuminator are hidden as they are significantly out of focus. Therefore Köhler illuminators are often built from singlet lenses (i.e. without correction of chromatic aberration).

Still, when observing reflective features I often observe residual color in out of focus areas. When slightly in/out of focus reflective features will have blue/red halo. When in focus - there is no residual color (as microscope lens is apochromatic).

**This is how it looks like.** Center image is in focus (some softness due to oversampling, this is 100% crop). Green-blue tint when sample moved down (slight more distance to lens). Red-purple tint when sample moved up (slightly less distance to lens). RGB LED light source (i.e. no infrared or UV):

[image: Color bokeh example]

My understanding is that reflective features will preserve wavefront with all it's aberrations, including ones of the illuminator and it might became visible in out-of-focus areas. I suspect color bokeh can be caused by differential vignetting of different colors inside microscope lens (as they have slightly different numeric aperture after lens entry aperture).

**Is this phenomenon (color bokeh on reflective out-of-focus features) known in optical microscopy, and how can it be eliminated?**

Making all lenses achromatic in Köhler illuminator is likely impractical (as condenser/aperture lenses typically have high aperture, which is likely not feasible for doublets).

Making last (field) lens achromatic is easy, but I am not sure if this can help as it has lowest aperture / aberrations.

[image: Thorlabs WFA2001 Epi-Illuminator Module optical scheme]

Comment: I don't think my comment warrants an actual answer but: I think what you are seeing with an apochromat is normal, you would expect to see red and blue "come to focus" at different focal lengths, or rather, they will show up more visibly at some points, I think that is normal. If you are worried about the illumination effects, do you have short/long pass to determine where your chromatic aberration (CA) is coming from? It is also possible that the eyepiece (or wherever your camera is located) has some degree of CA so the artifacts are from your image capture system rather than the objective

Comment: @ondas I would expect that if red and blue lines come at focus at different focal lengths - I would not see middle in-focus image with no color. System does not have filters - as I am using RGB LED light source, so all light is between 440 and 670nm, well within corrected wavelength range of imaging optics. There are only 2 imaging lenses: apochromatic microscope lens and microscope tube lens, then camera.